# Spring boot CommandLineRunner invokes all classes with run method

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-boot

I have multiple classes which uses CommandLineRunner for running the application. But when i start the application using spring-boot-maven-plugin all the classes are invoked one after another. This happens even if I run the class as main method. How can I overcome this. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Using the below code in pom to identify the main method

`<plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.4.RELEASE</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>com.Foo</mainClass>
                    <layout>ZIP</layout>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>`

Comment: That is what the `CommandLineRunner` interface is for. If you don't want Spring to call the run method on those classes, stop implementing the interface.

Comment: @ESala Thanks for replying. I was looking for any option to override this behavior.

Answer (score 2):

A potential solution for you, that I used to get around a similar problem. Similar, but not exact same, so I can't guarentee success.

You can try using [@ConditionalOnExpression](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/condition/ConditionalOnExpression.html) on each implementation, with different values. Like so: `@ConditionalOnExpression("'${some.property}'=='myValue'")`.

Add the property in `application.properties` to set a default implementation, and when running the jar you can override that implementation with `java -jar myApp.jar --some.property=myOtherValue`.

Spring boot should select the correct implementation to use, based on which implementation matches the value of the property you set.